# How generate a list of rows of numers in a range in HSQLDB?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

How generate a list of rows of numers in a range in HSQLDB?

I need to insert a whole range of numbers in the base.

something like this

```
INSERT INTO numers
VALUES
(50001)
(50002)
...
(59999)
```

In oracle, is can be done with "CONNECT BY LEVEL", but how can i do it in HSQLDB?

Comment: You can use a procedure. Just take a look on hsqldb example in the documenation : http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_psm_handlers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HyperSQL (as HSQLDB is now called) has a function similar to Postgres' `generate_series()`. Using `sequence_array` together with the `unnest()` function you can generate a list of values:

```
insert into numbers (some_number)
select nr
from unnest(sequence_array(1, 100, 1)) as i(nr)
```

If you want to start with a different number, just supply that as an argument to the `sequence_array` function.

```
insert into numbers (some_number)
select nr
from unnest(sequence_array(50000, 59999, 1)) as i(nr)
```

Comment: What does that `i(nr)` mean?